# Regex pattern to exclude specific words at the start of url using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

[Edited code]*

This is the current code I am using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (bus/(.*))
RewriteRule bus/(.*) page1.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (car/(.*)) 
RewriteRule car/(.*) test/page2.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (bike/(.*))
RewriteRule bike/(.*) test/page3.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ new.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I am trying to get the wild card condition in the last line if the above conditions fail. But the server returning with the 404. Its not catching the condition.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all specific rules are top and 3rd generic catch-all rule at the last:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^bus/(.+)$ page1.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^car/(.+)$ test/page2.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^bike/(.+)$ test/page3.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ new.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Two `RewriteCond` are required before last rule to prevent rewriting actual files and directories.

Comment: Hey.. I tried both. I am getting '.php' error. It says param1/param2.php is not found on this server. I am using two lines of code that strips .php in URLs- [ ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] ]. Not sure if it is causing any problem or not.

Comment: Rule in your comment is not shown on your question. Can you update the question with your full htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Your need to use the L flag at the end of your rules to stop multiple rule processing :

```
RewriteRule ^ask/(.*) forum.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^city/(.*) city.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
```